# G++ flags to disable "temporary to non-const reference" error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am looking for some command-line flags (should they exist) that disable the GCC error for this type of C++ code:

```
#include <string>

void m(std::string& s) { }

int main()
{
        m(std::string(""));
}
```

G++ gives this error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'std::string'

The reason is to be able to quickly migrate from VC++ and Sun Studio (without any code changes), since both silently accept temporary to non-const lvalue ref conversions. I know what needs to be done in terms of code changes -- I am strictly asking about a way to do it **without making code changes**.

I will be using GCC 4.x.

Comment: G++ likely does not have a flag to remove this error.

Comment: I've encountered this exact issue, also with porting VC code to GCC. There is no option to disable this error in GCC. You can confirm this for yourself by looking at where the error is issued, in gcc/cp/call.c (function initialize_reference in 4.6). You'll have to fix the code. (Or patch GCC to understand this syntax)

Comment: Even if you could somehow disable the error, the code still wouldn’t work. Be thankful for the compiler flagging this for you. It seems that you *real* question is not how disable the error, it’s how to enable the VC++ vendor extension in G++. Which is something quite different.

Comment: @Jack Lloyd, thanks for the tip. Why not make it an answer? :)

Comment: @VJo: Disabling warnings is not what Nick wants. He wants disabling of errors.

Comment: @VJo: I think you misunderstood. Obviously, he wants disabling the errors but still keeping a "correct" build :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not conforming to the standard & there is no way to disable this through flags in GCC.

Vc++ wrongly supports this through an non-standard extension. Try with `/Za` (disable language extension) flag, and you should see the errors.

Or use can the `/W4` flag to get maximum warnings, and it will show you:

`warning C4239: nonstandard extension used`

Comment: Yes, I know how to enable this error in VC++. Do you know how to enable it in Sun Studio?

Comment: @Nick With Sun Studio, use the `+w2` commandline option. It tells me `Warning: should not initialize a non-const reference with a temporary.`

Comment: Awarded as most to the point answer -- though I welcome Jack Lloyd's approach to digging into gcc code

Answer (score 4):

Why should one want to disable an **error**? Fix the code instead of relying on vendor extensions.

Comment: Yes, of course -- but how exactly does that answer my question?

Comment: I am afraid the answer is "g++ does not have a flag to disable this error". Sorry for just mentioning the consequence of this; but my questioning answer stands valid.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to build your code with CLang.

There has been much work on CLang to get compatibility with VC++ source files (both the STL and the MFC code) and as a consequence CLang has the `-fms-extensions` flag to allow these extensions, and generate the appropriate code.

Most of MFC compile, so most of the extensions, including other oddities in templates, are covered too.